# Rename Win32 Functions for Security on C++

Tags: c++, security, obfuscation

Is there a way to rename a win32 function like GetVolumeInformationW() using #define ?

For example:
`#define abc(LPCWSTR a, LPWSTR b, ...) GetVolumeInformationW(Some argumments..)`

Why do that? I want to hide the function name on debbuger programms like IDA, is there some way to did that?

Language: C++

Comment: `#define` is not for this purpose because it mean string replacement will be done before compiling.

Comment: Obfuscation is not security... and this isn't even obfuscation

Comment: Do you know how `#define` works? It does textual replacement before the compiler even runs. So your generated assembly doesn't contain any of those anyways. Frankly "keyword" starting with `#` (e.g. `#include`) is processed by preprocessor, which gets invoked before compiler. EDIT: "_Language: C++_" Why did you tag C, then?

Comment: You are "hiding" the function names from debugger by stripping down the debug info from the binaries. Surely it won't help with *standard* precompiled libraries though.

Comment: The short answer is **no**.  `#define` will not rename any function, nor will it hide a name from the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point in using `#define` for this, as this will have no effect on the contents of the binary executable. Using preprocessor macros will only affect what you as a programmer will see, but it won't affect what the compiler or linker will see. See [this link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases) for information on how the C++ preprocessor works and its relationship with the compiler/linker.

If you do not want the function to appear in the [Import Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#the-idata-section) of your executable, then you can instead load the function dynamically using [`GetProcAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getprocaddress). That way, a disassembler will probably be unable to determine which function the address is pointing to, when the function is being called. However, the disassembler will be able to see that you are using `GetProcAddress` for something, it just won't know what. Using the function `GetProcAddress` may make someone trying to crack your software suspicious, because that is a common thing to do if you are trying to hide something.

If you do not want the string `GetVolumeInformationW` to appear in cleartext in your executable file, then you can somehow encrypt or obfuscate it, for example store it in reverse and then reverse it back before passing it to `GetProcAddress`. This was just a very simple example of how it could be done. Using XOR (which is the `^` operator in C++) on every character with a certain key to encrypt, and then do the same thing again to decrypt, would probably be a better solution, as this would make the the encrypted text not be easily identifiable as text.

Answer (score 1):

You'll be calling a function out of a shared DLL. Defines are strictly preprocessor.

What you want to do is create a hash function to hash the string "GetVolumeInformationW". As well as the name of the module thats in. For example "Kernel32.dll"

Get the [PEB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_Environment_Block) using the FS or GS register. Then go to the PEB_LDR_DATA list. Run each list entry and hash the DLL name against your Kernel32 hashed string. If the hashes match, you grab the base of the library in that same structure.

After this you will then trace the export table. And do the same thing you did above, where you compare each export name to the hashed "GetVolumeInformationW" string. When it's found, you will then call the address it's at using a function pointer.

This is the sole way to do it. Bonus points if the encrypted strings are stored on the stack. So when coding it do

char[] szKernel32 = 'K', 'e', 'r', 'n'.........;

Also, do not use `GetProcAddress`. It defeats the point of hiding, since anyone experienced with IDA will instantly search for `GetProcAddress`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to rename a win32 function like GetVolumeInformationW() using #define ?

No, macros do not serve that purpose.  You could define a macro such that Win32 function names do not appear literally *in your source code*, other than in the macro definitions, but that does not rename the functions, nor even prevent the function names from appearing in your compiled object files, libraries, or executables.

It can't, because the Win32 API's function names are established by the platform headers and (especially) libraries.  You're not rebuilding the platform libraries, only linking the existing ones to your own code, so your code has no alternative but to use the API's function names to call API functions.

> Why do that? I want to hide the function name on debbuger programms like IDA, is there some way to did that?

Obfuscation is not a very effective defense technique.  It is far more likely to make trouble for you, in the ordinary development of your software, than to present a major hurdle to a skilled adversary.  You can obfuscate the names of your own functions if you nevertheless wish to do so, but no, you cannot change the names of platform API functions.

Comment: Hummm, thank you very much!! You are very intelligent

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.  I have code that does it that I am going to convert because mainly you should know when you are using Win32 vs your own function wrapper so would not advice doing this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).